# Read Related data from firebase using React js Hook

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Check Above Image Read data from 2120063456 child and display in table working perfectly but I want to fetch email, name from users child using usersid. I want

Table  ----> phonenumber --- deviceid ---- devicename --- email --- name ---

email and name taken from users child

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import Contactform from "./Contactform"
import firbaseDB from "../firebase"

const Contact = () => {
    var [contactsObjects,setContactObjects] = useState({})
    useEffect(()=>{
        firbaseDB.child("2120063456").on("value", snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.val())
            if(snapshot.val()!=null)
            {
                setContactObjects({...snapshot.val()})
            }
            else{
                setContactObjects({})
            }
        })
    },[])
    return (  
        <>
        <div className = "row">
            <div className="col-md-7">
            
                <table className="table table-broderless table stripped">
                <thead className = "thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Device ID</th>
                        <th>Device Name</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   { 
                        Object.keys(contactsObjects).map(id =>{
                            return <tr key={id}>
                                <td>{contactsObjects[id].phonenumber}</td>
                                <td>{contactsObjects[id].deviceid}</td>
                                <td>{contactsObjects[id].devicename}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="/#" className = "btn text-primary">
                                        <i className = "fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="/#" className = "btn text-danger">
                                        <i className = "fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        })
                   }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    );
}
export default Contact;
```

Below Code is My Firebase Configuration

firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase";
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyDyRJbzlHGRJxfc1RIYRnjPyATjYJCIC-h8",
        authDomain: "fir-XXXX.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://firXXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "fir-XXXXX",
        storageBucket: "fir-XXXXXX.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "73797XXXXXXXXXX",
        appId: "1:737979XXXXXXX:web:bb2b676dXXXXXXXXX"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      var firedb = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      export default firedb.database().ref();
```

My Expected Output image
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: So you need to read userid from each object present in `"2120063456"` and then get objects of all those users from the "users" node?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Dharmaraj.. Yes Help me to solve this I am very beginner in react with firebase

Comment: Hey, I've posted an answer based on the data flow. Let me know if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useEffect(()=>{
  firbaseDB.child("2120063456").once("value").then(async (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val())
    if(snapshot.val() !== null) {
      //Reading all userIDs
      const userRefs = []
      Object.keys(snapshot.val()).forEach((user) => {
        userRefs.push(firebaseDB.child("users").child(snapshot.val()[user]["usersid"]).once("value"))
      })
      const usersSnapshots = await Promise.all(userRefs)
      usersSnapshots.forEach((userSnap) => {
        console.log(userSnap.val())
      })
      setContactObjects({...snapshot.val()})
    } else{
      setContactObjects({})
    }
  })
},[])
```

After fetching the first snapshot from the numerical ID, you can add all the promises to get data from users node in an array as shown above and run them. Once the promise is fulfilled you will get an array of [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot).

> Returned values from Promise all will be in order of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order.

You can read more about [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: I got TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.ref is not a function
 @Dharmaraj

Comment: @Arasan can you please edit your question and add how you are importing and initializing Firebase?

Comment: I am using firebase node version 7.14.1

Comment: @Arasan that error was because you are already exporting the db with `.ref()` here `export default firedb.database().ref();`. So please try my updated answer: `     userRefs.push(firebaseDB.child("users").child.(snapshot.val()[user]["usersid"]).once("value"))`

Comment: Thanks @Dharmaraj get all data from users but ...snapshot.val() does not have users node  data

Comment: How to combine ...snapshot.val() and userSnap.val()

Comment: @Arasan can you share a screenshot of what is your expected output ?